# Solar System using OpenGL-ES 2.0 and GLSL 1.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to implement the classic solar system (Sun & Earth only - cubes in place of spheres) application using OpenGLES 2.0 and GLSL 1.0. I am not getting how to

- write the translation and rotation matrix to get the Earth cube revolving around the Sun.
- what should be order of matrix multiplication.
  I am doing all the matrix operation in the vertex shader and have got the two cubes rotating along x and y axis respectively.

  [image: Earth and Sun in form of cubes]

But facing problem in getting the Earth cube revolve around the Sun cube :-(

Answer (score 0):

first you have to understand Matrix 
ES 1.X is better If you dont't know exactly
1. translation matrix is
1000
0100
0010
xyz1 
Change X and Z valute
2. angle matrix is
c s 00
-s c 00
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1
also change X & Y axis

then operation martix in code ( not shader code )
and just give matirx to shader's uniforms each obejct